# How to disable FileSystemWatcher's Created event from firing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Question is as per below code, will setting EnableRaisingEvents = false disable all or Create event from firing? Please advise

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"D:\Outgoing", "*.txt");
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
```

Comment: Why don't you make a try with your code?

Comment: I tried watcher.Create+=Watcher_Handler but this will add the Create event. I'm looking for disabling Create event

Answer (score 2):

`EnableRaisingEvents` property of the file system watcher will helps you to enable or disable raising events. if you set this property to false then it won't raise any events for all the actions, if you don't need Created event means you need not to subscribe the created event. which means the definition of the watcher object would be like the following:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"D:\Sujith\Test folder");
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_changed);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(watcher_renamed);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_deleted);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

This is not actually disabling the created event raising, it will raise the event but we haven't subscribe them

Comment: Thanks @un-lucky. To be precise, I want to disable or suppress the Created event problematically in such a way that no other program can use it. If a third party is waiting for Created event to be triggered, my code/program should disable it completely or enable or disable it as I wish

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you don't want 'Created' event (perhaps, you wanted other events like Changes, Deleted, Renamed...) to be notified). If so, you can subscribe only to the needed events. Something like as follows,

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher(@"D:\Outgoing", "*.txt");
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
//watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated); // not interested
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
...
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Well thanks @Shankar. To be precise, I want to disable or suppress the Created event problematically in such a way that no other program can use it. If a third party is waiting for Created event to be triggered, my code/program should disable it completely or enable or disable it as I wish.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Another FileSystemWatcher instance (from another application) would pick up the created event anyway.